# Finding one time series signal among 1000 incoming signals

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, time-series, statistics

I have **one** IoT signal, which should be recognized among 1000 incoming IoT signals. However, I receive only values and signalID. What approach would you suggest for this kind of problem?
I have done a lot of time-series classification problems, but here, I have a lot of signals which are not trained.

My dataset is straightforward:

| timestamp | signalA |
| --- | --- |
| t1 | value1A |
| t2 | value2A |
| ... | ... |

The dataset I get from IoT devices has the same structure, but 1000 columns. Therefore, I should recognize the signal A in that dataset.

Comment: Could you add some samples? Many solutions are possible, but adding some samples (even simulated ones) would help to reduce the potential solutions.

Comment: @NicolasMartin Hi, I added the description of the dataset. What possible approaches would you suggest?